# what does, "passing argument 2 of 'strstr' makes pointer from integer without a cast," mean in C

Tags: c, arguments

I'm trying to have a list of cheeses that you can search through to get to a certain one. When I am done I also want to add info about each one. But every time I run my code I get the error shown in the title. Here is my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
   {    
    char cheeses[][20] = {
        "Cheddar",
        "White Cheddar",
        "Colby Jack",
        "Gouda",
        "Blue Cheese",
        "Gorgonzola",
        "Asiago", 
        "Limburger",
        "Feta",
        "Brie",
     };

         void find_cheese(char search_for)
     {
         int i;
         for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             if (strstr(cheeses[i], search_for))
                 printf("Cheese %i: '%s'\n", i, cheeses[i]);
          }
    }

int main()
    {
        char search_for[20];
        printf("Search for: ");
        fgets(search_for, 20, stdin);
        find_cheese(search_for);
        return 0;
     }
}
```

Why is this happening? I've looked it up in my book, but can't seem to find the answer.

Comment: ...I'm assuming you don't really have an `int main()` wrapped around another `int main()` right? typo right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument to [strstr](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) should be `const char*`.  You're passing a single `char`.

Comment: That works great, but now it says "'main' is normally a non-static function," now what @simonc ?

Comment: @BrandonDamante Your code sample has two main()s, one wrapped inside the other.  I presume this is a typo.  Can you update it please?  This should make it easy to spot your next problem.

Answer (score 2):

`strstr` expects a pointer to `char` as the second argument:

```
const char * strstr ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

while you are passing a `char`.

Answer (score 0):

```
void find_cheese(char search_for)
```

should be

```
void find_cheese(char *search_for)
```

because it is looking for a string (`char *`), not a single character.

Answer (score 0):

`strstr()` takes a string (char *) as the second argument.
For usage see [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strstr/).

The problem in your code is you're accepting the passed the array incorrectly:

```
    void find_cheese(char search_for) //This line is wrong
    {
```

What you wanted to do was:

```
    void find_cheese(char search_for[])
```

**EDIT:**

Here's what is happening. When you access the array in your main function:

```
find_cheese(search_for);
```

What you're actually doing here is passing an address. (When you just access the array `search_for` you get an address). So when your prototype said it was taking a `char` the compiler saw the address (4 bytes, looking like an int) and truncated it to fit in a one byte char.

The way you prevent that is by passing the whole "string" (a string in C is a character array). So you can do this by passing `search_for` as an array, or as a pointer (address to a character array).

```
void find_cheese(char search_for[])
```

and

```
void find_cheese(char *search_for)
```

Will both work and are equivalent for your needs (passing to `strstr()`)